# How to change __init__ param before instantiation

Tags: python

I want to achieve a simple interface as such:

```
IsAllowed(perms=[IsAdmin(runtime_value) | HasPerm('*')])
```

Since some variables upon instantiation are not available, I have to postpone the evaluation of `perms=[IsAdmin() | HasPerm('*')]` to later point in time (when `__call__` is called on IsAllowed by the FastAPI webframework I'm using). The closest I have come to achieving that is the following:

```
IsAllowed(perms = lambda runtime_value: [IsAdmin(runtime_value) | HasPerm('*')])


class IsAllowed(object):
    def __init__(self, perms=None):
        self.perms = perms
    def __call__(self, runtime_value):
        result = self.perms(runtime_value)
        return result
```

No my question is, is there any way to keep the interface as `IsAllowed(perms=[IsAdmin(runtime_value) | HasPerm('*')])` but, somehow inject the `lambda` into it before instantiation?

I am thinking of maybe metaclasses or leveraging the `__init_subclass__` hook?
Any ideas?

Comment: `__init__` is called first then `__call__`. I think you should redisign your ideas, maybe with a decorator

Comment: interface `IsAllowed(perms=[IsAdmin, HasPerm('*')])` and `result = self.perms[0](runtime_value) | self.perms[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want something like that:

```
from typing import Any


class IsAllowed(object):
    def __init__(self, *perms):
        self.perms = perms


def __call__(self, args: list[Any]):
    return all(self.perms[i](args[i]) for i in range(len(args)))

checker = IsAllowed(IsAdmin, HasPerm)
checker(“somevalue”, “*”)
```

**UPDATE:**

For the cases mentioned in the comment section:

```
from typing import Any, Callable


class Operation:
    pass


class Or(Operation):
    def __init__(self, *funcs: Callable[[Any], bool]) -> None:
        self.funcs = funcs
        
    def __call__(self, val: Any) -> bool:
        return any(func(val) for func in self.funcs)
    
    def __or__(self, other: Operation) -> Operation:
        return Or(*self.funcs, other.func)


class Predicate:
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[Any], bool]) -> None:
        self.func = func
        
    def __or__(self, other) -> Or:
        return Or(self.func, other.func)
    
    
def Is1(x: int) -> bool:
    return x == 1
    
    
def Is2(x: int) -> bool:
    return x == 2
    
    
def Is3(x: int) -> bool:
    return x == 3
    
    
def main() -> None:
    pred1 = Predicate(Is1)
    pred2 = Predicate(Is2) 
    pred3 = Predicate(Is3)
    
    fancy_pred = pred1 | pred2 | pred3
    
    for i in range(5):
        print(fancy_pred(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The important difference is that I want to define the bitwise logic explicitly on IsAllowed. So it looks like: `IsAllowed(IsAdmin | HasPerm)`

Comment: Well, you need to implement a class, which will store all predicates and logical operations between them. All predicates should inherit from some class (or implement the abstract one), for which you overloaded logical operations. The important think here is input. It will be never explicit fully, if your predicates uses different input, like in example. To solve it you can either use predicates with same input, or provide some data class, from which predicates will get data they need

Comment: Hmm, yeah I think this is the way to go. I could maybe keep the inputs similar. Can you share a snippet?

Comment: I can but later. You actually can take a look at SymPy GitHub: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/. They use the same approach for symbolic calculations.

Comment: @AmirAfianian, snippet is provided :0